# Ngrok not getting along with Tomcat

Tags: jsp, tomcat, ngrok

I am using Ngrok and want to access a JSP subdirectory ie `IP_ADDRESS/8080/JSP_Trial_war_exploded/Trials/FILE.jsp` (**NOT** `localhost`). What I have tried `./ngrok http -host-header=JSP_Trial_war_exploded/Trials/FILE.jsp IP_ADDRESS:8080` but I am getting a response from Tomcat `Message: The character [_] is never valid in a domain name.`
What am I doing wrong? Please do not suggest use of `localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `-host-header rewrite` which will add the upstream service host:port to the host header. Then you can access your JSP subdirectory with: `NGROK_URL/JSP_Trial_war_exploded/Trials/FILE.jsp`

source: https://ngrok.com/docs#http-host-header